# How to create a data associatively? laravel eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-6, eloquent-relationship

I have a **Post** model:

```
class Post extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'title',
        'user_id',
        'token',
        'body'
    ];

    public function favorites()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Favorite::class);
    }

    public function addFavorite($state = 1)
    {
        $this->favorites()->create(compact('state'));
    }
}
```

**Favorite** model:

```
class Favorite extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['user_id', 'post_id', 'state'];
}
```

When I test in tinker:

```
$post = Post::first();
$post->addFavorite();
```

It returns me an error below:

> Illuminate/Database/QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[HYOOO]: General error: 1364 Field 'user_id' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into favorites...

Why it ask `user_id` when it is given in the post? Question is do I necessarily need to input the `user_id` to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question of whether `user_id` is necessary is up to you. Will it come in handy later on? Does having it on the posts table suffice?

It is asking for `user_id` because you do not have a default value field on that field in the favorites table. You can either set a default value, remove it from the table (if you decide you don't need it), OR provide it when creating via the relationship:

```
class Post extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'title',
        'user_id',
        'token',
        'body'
    ];

    public function addFavorite($state = 1)
    {
        $this->favorites()->create([
            'state' => $state,
            'user_id' => $this->user_id,
        ]);
    }

    public function removeFavorite()
    {
        $this->addFavorite(0);
    }
}
```

Don't forget to include the relationship definition of `favorites` on the Post model.

Based on the plural name, it seems that a post has many favorites, but then your removeFavorite() method calls the addFavorite method?? This would not actually remove anything - it would create a new record.

Answer (score 2):

Since `Favorite` model is related to `Post` model and you create it via `relation()->create()`, you can skip specifying `post_id` as Laravel can deduce it. But you do have to specify `user_id`, because there's no way for your code to know that `favourite.user_id` and `post.user_id` is the same. So in short: **yes, you have to specify user_id**.

Comment: ahws so no way to handle this. I need to hardcode `$this->user_id`.